# Hidding view tab on node/%/view

Tags: hooks, routes

I've successfully managed to hide "View" tab on node page with this code:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data){


    foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['#link']['path'] == "node/%/view"){
            unset($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

but when I enter the frontpage this error is displayed:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in custom_alter_menu_local_tasks_alter()... 
>   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in custom_alter_menu_local_tasks_alter()...

This line that causes the error is the following.

```
foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
```

I don't know what is wrong with the code. On frontpage there are no tabs and I don't have custom coding there.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what is your purpose but to pass this error you just do that

```
/*
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data){
  if(isset($data['tabs'][0]) && is_array($data['tabs'][0])){
    foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
      if ($value['#link']['path'] == "node/%/view"){
        unset($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this code is OK. Now I don't have the error. I can see the correction. If statement with this line: **if(isset($data['tabs'][0]) && is_array($data['tabs'][0])){** Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this is not the correct hook to implement. The hook that should be used to alter menu items defined from another module is `hook_menu_alter()`.

Comment: That's right. With hook_menu_alter() it will be simple. Reference : https://drupal.org/node/483324

Answer (score 2):

The way to hide the node/%/view tab is to implement [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7), and change the menu defined from the Node module, which uses the following definitions.

```
  $items['node/%node'] = array(
    'title callback' => 'node_page_title',
    'title arguments' => array(1),

    // The page callback also invokes drupal_set_title() in case
    // the menu router's title is overridden by a menu link.
    'page callback' => 'node_page_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('view', 1),
  );
  $items['node/%node/view'] = array(
    'title' => 'View',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -10,
  );
  $items['node/%node/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'page callback' => 'node_page_edit',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('update', 1),
    'weight' => 0,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
    'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
  );
```

In particular, you need to change the menu type for node/%node/view from `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK` to `MENU_CALLBACK`, and change the type for node/%node/edit from `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` to `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK`.

`MENU_CALLBACK` keeps the menu item still accessible for those users who have the permission to see it, but the menu item would not be visible as tab or link.

As for using [`hook_local_task_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7), I don't see Drupal core modules that alter the tabs added from other modules, but looking at [blog_local_task_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!blog!blog.module/function/blog_menu_local_tasks_alter/7), I notice the following code.

```
  if ($root_path == 'blog') {
    $item = menu_get_item('node/add/blog');
    if ($item['access']) {
      $item['title'] = t('Create new blog entry');
      $data['actions']['output'][] = array(
        '#theme' => 'menu_local_action',
        '#link' => $item,
      );
    }
  }
  // Provide a helper action link to the author on the 'blog/%' page.
  elseif ($root_path == 'blog/%' && $router_item['page_arguments'][0]->uid == $user->uid) {
    $data['actions']['output']['blog'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'menu_local_action',
    );
    if (user_access('create blog content')) {
      $data['actions']['output']['blog']['#link']['title'] = t('Post new blog entry.');
      $data['actions']['output']['blog']['#link']['href'] = 'node/add/blog';
    }
    else {
      $data['actions']['output']['blog']['#link']['title'] = t('You are not allowed to post a new blog entry.');
    }
  }
```

In your case, you should check that `$root_path` is equal to node/%; in that way you would avoid to do something when the page being shown is the front page. (If node/% doesn't work, then node/%node should.)

I still think that `hook_local_tasks_alter()` should not be used in this case, as it seems to me that `hook_local_tasks_alter()` is thought to be used when altering the tabs depends from the page being viewed, as `blog_local_task_alter()` shows.